# my React app is not auto reloading in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app is not auto refreshing. But in the terminal it shows "Compiled successfully".

and there is a message in the console :

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
```

I have to manually reload the browser to see the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to VS code settings > auto save and change it to AfterDelay, thats how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but got the fix by importing React Hot Loader and making some changes in the babel.

Reference link for react hot loader :

https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader